# libgdx - place a table on the top-right corner of the screen

Tags: user-interface, libgdx

I'm experiencing an issue placing a "table" in the top-right corner of my screen:

```
|----------|
|         X|
|          |
|          |
|----------|

Table statusTable = new Table(skin);
statusTable.add(new DateLabel(skin));
statusTable.row();
statusTable.add(new TextButton("Funds:", skin));
statusTable.row();
statusTable.add(new TextButton("Tax rate:", skin));
...
this.statusTable.setPosition(width, height, Align.bottomLeft);
```

Reaching the #setPosition point, the table's width and height are set to 0 so the positioning stands centered on the corner somehow:

```
|----------X
|          |
|          |
|          |
|----------|
```

I guess I don't understand well what this alignment is about, and before coding my own algorithm I'd like to know if a better practice would exist.

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding the table directly to the stage (e.g. it is not inside some other table), it would be easier to set the table widget to fill it's parent, and then set its gravity to the top right so its logical table (the actual cells within the widget) is pulled up to the corner.

```
Table statusTable = new Table(skin);
statusTable.add(new DateLabel(skin));
statusTable.row();
statusTable.add(new TextButton("Funds:", skin));
statusTable.row();
statusTable.add(new TextButton("Tax rate:", skin));

// ...

statusTable.top().right();
statusTable.setFillParent(true);
stage.addActor(statusTable);
```

By the way, the reason your method didn't work is that the table's size hasn't been calculated yet if it hasn't been drawn yet, and you're using the opposite corner of what you want to align. You could call `statusTable().pack()` before your `setPosition` call, and it should work assuming `width` and `height` are the coordinates of the top right corner of the viewport and you used `Align.topRight`.

Comment: that didn't work for me, the table is out of screen i guess; btw i've got Stage stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport(), batch);

Comment: => sorry, you were right, i just missed the #pack call!

Answer (score 1):

Size is computed at runtime, and since you don't know the size of the table, I would let another table calculate its position.

I would add an empty expanded cell before the *statusTable*, both inside a *rootTable* that fills the entire stage (using **setFillParent()**)

```
┌────────┬───┐
│        │ X │ -> empty expandX cell | statusTable | row
├────────┴───┤
│            │
│            │ -> empty expand, colspan(2) cell
│            │
└────────────┘
```

Another 'solution' could  be setting the table position at runtime

```java
Table statusTable = new Table(skin) {
    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Align.topRight);
    }

};
```

Comment: Note the code above works only with a `ScreenViewport` and with a camera that has been centered to the viewport's world center, since it is using screen width and height as the assumed coordinates of the top right of the screen.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the top() or right() methods applied to the table.